# How Ti.Locale.getCurrentLanguage() , i18n defferent?

Tags: internationalization, titanium

My Tianium application uses i18n.
I have four folders under i18n.

> en/ ja/ zh-CN/ zh-TW/

zh-CN is Chinese used in Mainland china.
zh-TW is Chinese used in Taiwan.

it works well for i18n.

Now I want to get this name, in app.js. However, as for `Ti.Locale.getCurrentLanguage()`, both Taiwan and Mainland china returns `'zh'`.

How can I tell zh-CN or zh-TW ???

----Solution----
Thanks to @DC Jmz

use `Ti.Locale.getCurrentLocale()`

```
if ( Ti.Locale.getCurrentLocale().match(/zh-Hant/)) {
    Ti.App.global.lang = 'zh-TW'; // taiwan letters
}
if ( Ti.Locale.getCurrentLocale().match(/zh-Hans/)) {
    Ti.App.global.lang = 'zh-CN'; // mainland china letters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using     `Ti.Platform.getLocale()`

> System's default language.
>
> Locale, as a combination of ISO 2-letter language and country codes. For example, en-US or en-GB. See the ISO 639-1 and ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 sections of wikipedia for reference.

Comment: Thanks to you , I accomplish.